# How can I write a variable in one place of command window and update its value at the same place?

Tags: c++, gcc, printing

for example the output is  ***a=20*** I want to change the number *"20"* to another number and write the result at the same place of first output, not in a new line (the earliest amount of *"a"* is not required just the last result is important)
I try to avoid something like this:

**output:**

```
a=20
a=21
a=70
.
.
.
```

Comment: an old-school alternative could be to use libcurses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
printf("\ra=%d",a);
// \r=carriage return, returns the cursor to the beginning of current line
```

Comment: You should probably flush it after each print, like this: `printf("\ra=%d",a); fflush(stdout);`

Answer (score 4):

Formally, the generic solution would require something like `ncurses`.
Practically, if all you're looking for is to have a line like:

```
a = xxx
```

Where `xxx` is a value which constantly evolves, you can output the line
without a `'\n'` (or a `std::flush` instead of `std::endl`); to update,
just output enough `\b` characters to get back to the start of the
number.  Something like:

```
std::cout << "label = 000" << std::flush;
while ( ... ) {
    //  ...
    if ( timeToUpdate ) {
        std::cout << "\b\b\b" << std::setw(3) << number << std::flush;
    }
}
```

This supposes fixed width formatting (and in my example, no values
larger than 999).  For variable width, you can first format into an
std::ostringstream, in order to determine the number of backspaces
you'll have to output next time around.  I'd use a special counter type
for this:

```
class DisplayedCounter
{
    int myBackslashCount;
    int myCurrentValue;
public:
    DisplayedCounter()
        : myBackslashCount(0)
        , myCurrentValue(0)
    {
    }
    //  Functions to evolve the current value...
    //  Could be no more than an operator=( int )
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& dest,
        DisplayedCounter const& source )
    {
        dest << std::string( myBackslashCount, '\b' );
        std::ostringstream tmp;
        tmp << myCurrentValue;
        myBackslashCount = tmp.str().size();
        dest << tmp.str() << std::flush();
        return dest;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The last time I had to do this (back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth and denim was cool), we used [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29).

Comment: @Brady it looks pretty obvious to me: you're not cool anymore.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, at least I threw away my parachute pants last year :) Ok, who knows what those are?

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the outputs you need and re-draw the entire console window each time a value is changed. No idea on Linux, but on Windows you can clear the console with:

```
system("cls");
```